# Relation with dynamic entity laravel 4

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I got this big question on this scenario:
I'm building a easy post and comment system, but with the difference that i have 2 main entity, wich are:
- User
- Team
So i have abviously 2 tables for it:

**Table User:**

```
id | name | surname | fullname     | image_profile |
 1   jhon     smith   jhon smith     apple.jpg
```

**Table Team**

```
id | fullname     | image_profile |
1    BKA Sport      three.jpg
```

Each user can let posts or comments and same thing for the team.

So i have setup my table Post with a column that difference the entity of the poster like so

**Table Post**

```
id | title_post |    body    | poster_id | poster_type | wall_id | wall_type
1     test         woo          1           User             1      Team
2     test 2       excellent    1           Team             1      User
3     test3        perfect      1           Team             1      Team
```

as you can see i setup even the column wall where this post as been released, in this case the User with ID 1 as wrote a post on the Wall of the team with ID 1,

and the Team has wrote on the Wall of the User with ID 1.
on the third result the Team has leaved a post on his own wall.

Now if i want to select all the wall posts of the "entity or poster_type" Team associating it the right entity how i have to set up my relations?

For now i just did a dirty solution without relationship but merging the results with an array, i think it's heavy for the server but i didn't find any way using relations. I even thought to use the polymorphic relation but it seem does't do the job well.

**Here how i did for now**

```
<?php

$posts = Post::where('wall_id','=','1')->where('wall_type','=','Team')->get()->toArray(); 

// I get just the id of the current posters
foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
            if ($value["poster_type"] == "User") {
                $poster['User'][$key]['id'] = $value['poster_id'];
            }

            if ($value['poster_type'] == "Team") {
                $poster['Team'][$key]['id'] = $value['poster_id'];
            }
 }

// all ids of the users
$user_ids = array_fetch($poster['User'],'id');
// all ids of the teams
$team_ids = array_fetch($poster['Team'],'id');

$users_informations = User::whereIn('id',array_unique($user_ids))->get()->toarray();
$teams_informations = User::whereIn('id',array_unique($team_ids))->get()->toarray();

// Here i merge the results
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check out [polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations), as it looks to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Ahh sorry I see you've said you knew about polymorphic relationships but they don't fit your use case. Maybe have another look just in case, but yeah maybe you're doing something that's a bit more than they can provide.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i'll do what you suggested. Hopefully is just my mistake to set up the polymorphic relation.